# How to activate bootstrap modal after selecting files in input in Vue 3?

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-modal

So, I'm doing a chat component and we've the option to send files, but prior to send it the user must review it and for it i had the idea to show a modal containing all the files selected, but i just can't show the modal right after the file selection, i tried getElementById but it did not work.

Here's my template:

```
    <input type="file" multiple name="file" id="fileInput" class="hidden-input" @change="onChange"
       ref="file" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" hidden />
    <button type="button" @click="chooseFiles()" class="btn btn-link text-decoration-none emoji-btn"
       id="emoji-btn">
       <i class="las la-arrow-up align-middle" />
    </button>
```

And here's my script:

```
    chooseFiles() {
      document.getElementById("fileInput").click()
      // document.getElementById("showModal").click()
    },
    onChange(e) {
      this.$refs.file.files = e.target.files
      this.files.push(...this.$refs.file.files)
      this.fileSize(e)
      // document.getElementById("showModal").click()
    },
```

And here is the modal:

```
  <div id="showModal" class="modal fade" ref="modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div v-for="file in files" :key="file.name" class="preview-card border rounded">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-2">
              <b-img v-if="file.type != 'application/pdf'" class="img-thumbnail me-2" alt="200x200" width="200"
                :src="generateURL(file)" data-holder-rendered="true" />
              <iframe v-else class="img-thumbnail me-2" data-holder-rendered="true" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no"
                alt="200x200" width="200" :src="generateURL(file)" />
              <div class="flex-grow-1">
                <div class="pt-1">
                  <h5 class="fs-11 mb-1" data-dz-name="">
                    {{ file.name }}
                  </h5>
                  <p class="fs-9 text-muted mb-0" data-dz-size="">
                    <strong>{{ (file.size / 1024) / 1000 }}</strong> MB
                  </p>
                  <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage="" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <b-button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
            Sair
          </b-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the button is coded to open the file select window, and should work based on the code provided so far (tested in [sandbox](https://jsfiddle.net/2co94n7r/2/)).  the button won't show a modal of all currently selected files, so I'm not sure if that's what you really want to do.  regardless, if you have an error opening the window you'll need to provide more context on how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: also, there's few reasons to use document `getElement` methods with Vue.  the more "Vue like" way of opening the window would be `this.$refs.file.click()`

Comment: @yoduh i want to show a modal after the selection of files (it would be triggered on onChange method), a tried the$refs.file and it did not work either, but thanks for the feedback!

Comment: As my sandbox shows, the current code provided all works.  So where is the modal in your code?  There's no element in your snippet with id "showModal"

Comment: so the modal is a `<div>`, which natively does not do anything when you call `.click()` on it.  If you're trying to conditionally render an element based on some state you'll find using [v-if](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html) is generally the way of going about it.  something like `v-if="files.length > 0"` on your modal's root element.  no need to access the DOM

Comment: It didn't work, tried with the modal in the app.vue and in a component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was commenting I missed the fact this was tagged `bootstrap-modal`, so I understand now you're wanting to open a bootstrap modal which has a specific method for activation.  For bootstrap 5 you can get the Modal instance with `bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance()`. Assign this to a data property and then you can call all the typical modal methods on it like `.show()`, `.toggle()`, `.hide()`, etc. Below is a working example using a more simplified modal than your own just for simplicity sake.

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" multiple name="file" id="fileInput" class="hidden-input" @change="onChange"
         ref="file" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" hidden />
  <button type="button" @click="chooseFiles" class="btn btn-link text-decoration-none emoji-btn"
          id="emoji-btn">
    choose files
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" ref="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Files</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div v-for="(file, i) in files" :key="i">
          {{ file.name }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
  data() {
    return {
      files: [],
      modal: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const myModalEl = this.$refs.modal
    this.modal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(myModalEl)
  },
  methods: {
    chooseFiles() {
        this.$refs.file.click()
    },
    onChange(e) {
      this.$refs.file.files = e.target.files
      this.files.push(...this.$refs.file.files)
      this.modal.show()
    },
  }
```

and here is the [sandbox](https://jsfiddle.net/2co94n7r/5/) with the above code

If bootstrap 5 is installed as a package you can do this instead:

```
import { Modal } from "bootstrap";
.
.
.
mounted() {
  this.modal = new Modal(this.$refs.modal);
}
```

Comment: it worked perfectly just how I wanted, can't find the words to thank you!! You rock! Wish you the best!